# $Y = e^{X^2}$, where $X ∼ N(0, 1)$. Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}P(Y^2\gt t)dt$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$Y = e^{X^2}$, where $X ∼ N(0,1)$. Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}P(Y^2\gt t)dt$.

I tried to solve it, but I got stuck somewhere. Please help me find it out.

**MY SOLUTION**
$\log Y=X^2$.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}P(Y^2\gt t)dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(2\log Y\gt \log t)dt$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}P(2\log Y\gt \log t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(\log Y\gt v)2e^vdv$$
where $v=\frac{\log t}{2}$
Let $W=X^2$. $W ∼  {\chi}^2_1$, that is $\log Y=W ∼ 
 {\chi}^2_1$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(\log Y\gt v)2e^vdv=2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1-P(W\lt v))e^vdv=2\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^vdv-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_W(w)e^vdv\right)$$

... And I have no idea

**Question Edited**
I made some progress and reposted the question. It seems to be related to the gamma distribution, but I can't figure out if it's a math error or what. Please help.

**MY SOLUTION**
$$F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y)=P(e^{X^2}\le y)=P(x^2\le \log y)=F_{X^2}(\log y)$$
$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{y}f_{X^2}(\log y)=\frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{\sqrt {\pi \log y}}e^{-\log y}dy$$ since $X^2∼\chi^2(1)$
$$\int_0^{\infty}P(Y^2\gt t)dt=E(Y^2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y^2f_Y(y)dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{y}{\sqrt {\pi \log y}}e^{-\log y}dy$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{y}{\sqrt {\pi \log y}}e^{-\log y}dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^v}{\sqrt {2\pi v}}e^ve^{-v}dv=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}v^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^vdv$$,where $v=\log y$
It seemas to be related to the Gamma distrbution, but somthing strange.

Comment: It's well known that if $U\geq 0$ a.s. and has density, then $$\mathbb E[U]=\int_0^\infty \mathbb P\{U>t\}\,\mathrm d t.$$ And if you don't know such result, then prove it ;-)

Comment: The integral is divergent? $E(e^{2X^2})\to\infty$ @Surb

Comment: I didn't calculate it, but it indeed seems to diverges to $\infty $...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First prove the equation in @Surb comment.

$$\int_0^\infty P(U>t)dt=\int_0^\infty \int_t^\infty f_U(u)dudt=\int_0^\infty \int_0^u f_U(u)dtdu=\int_0^\infty u f_U(u)du=E(U)$$

Then we have

$$\int_0^\infty P(Y^2>t)dt=E(e^{2X^2})=E(Y^2)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{2x^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac12x^2}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\frac32x^2}dx\to\infty$$

Above integral is divergent, can you confirm the OP?

Comment: Indeed, there is nothing wrong with problem, which came from Essentials of Probability for Statistics(Choi). The question I have with your solution is that you used the standard normal as the probability distribution function when averaging, but $Y^2$ does not follow the standard normal distribution. Please understand that I do not have a deep understanding of probability theory.